# Does anyone know what this set of aviation wings represent?

Tags: identification

Originally asked in the aviation stackexchange, though posted here under advice.

I stumbled upon this set of aviation wings whilst searching through a box of old things, though I'm at a loss as to their origin, and what they symbolise.

Judging from the lack of skill used to craft the item (Seems the mold had an off day), I doubt it's rare, though I could, very likely, be wrong.

Other than what you can see in the picture, the wings are roughly two inches long, and made of metal; sterling silver, perhaps?

As for background information, I did have Polish family who fought during WW2 in the west, and another who served in the RAF Regiment. There really isn't much else I can tell you, so I apologise for the ambiguity.

Still, I hope you can help!

[image: Resized]

[image: Rear]

Comment: Indeed, a bigger, sharper, picture would help.

Comment: A view of the back might help too.

Comment: Added a larger, clearer image.

Comment: Given the low quality of the piece, I'd be very surprised if this was an official badge of any self-respecting organisation. In fact the quality of the metal reminds me a lot of the toy sheriff's badge I had as a kid.

Comment: To be honest, that's my thinking too. Very poor quality for an official badge. Either way, though, it would be interesting to know of it's origin, even if it came from a cereal box.

Comment: What's the clip on the back made of? Is it plastic or metal?

Comment: Definitely plastic.

Comment: note: this has been crossposted from aviation.SE https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/42223/1467

Comment: the clip on the back looks like it was glued on later, rather than part of the original. Actual wings from the era had pins to attach them to clothing, not clips like that.

Comment: Do we actually have anything linking this object to the WW2 era? Do all of the other objects in the 'box of old things' date to the WW2 timeframe?

Comment: Oh, it was just a suggestion for what it could be, though there were objects of that era in the box. A numbered badge of the Polish 2nd Corps the main thing, but obviously, that has nothing to do with aviation. I suspect it's just something out of a cereal box, or something like that.

Comment: This page on [Aviators Badges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aviator_badge) seems to eliminate the military badges, although the crown is quite common.  Another option might be an airline pilots wings-perhaps one starting with 'Royal'. But there have been a lot of airlines. Also of note, the circle of twelves stars is also found on the [European Flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Europe), so perhaps this could be some commemorative or souvenir item of some sort?